# How to parse jsonObject and JsonArray for the same field in REST Response

Tags: json, rest, deserialization, resttemplate

I have calling a api using RestTemplate, let's suppose /getCompany

Usually response is as below:-

```
"Organization":{
  "name": "My Company",
  "department": {
     "id": "1",
     "employee": [{
       "id": "84",
       "name": "abc"
      },
      {
       "id": "85",
       "name": "xyz"
      }]
 }
}
```

So I am parsing this as below:-

```
ResponseEntity<Organization> company= new RestTemplate().exchange(new URI(companyUrl),HttpMethod.GET,request, Organization.class);
Organization comp= company.getBody();
Department dept= comp.getDepartment();
Employee[] emp = dept.getEmployees()
```

But sometimes in the response I am also getting the below json string:

```
"Organization":{
  "name": "My Company",
  "department": {
     "id": "1",
     "employee": {
       "id": "84",
       "name": "abc"
      }     
   }
}
```

Now I am getting the below Exception:-

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of Employee[] out of START_OBJECT token
```

So Is there any way to handle Both situation ?

Update:-

As per comment added the below code:-

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
    return objectMapper;
}

@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return converter;
}
```

But still getting the same exception.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The registered objectMapper must be used with [ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) parameter.

Maybe the easiest way to achive this is to register a properly initialized `ObjectMapper` and `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` in a class annotated with `@Configuration`:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.enable(ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
    return objectMapper;
}

@Bean
public MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return converter;
}
```

Another way is to set the converter directly to the restTemplate object:

```
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.enable(ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
    return objectMapper;
}


public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter httpConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper);
}

public void restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(Arrays.asList(httpConverter(objectMapper())));
    restTemplate.exchange(...);
}
```

Comment: How can i use it with my restTemplate call ? can you provide any example link ?

Comment: Just register these beans in a @Configuration class in your context and your restTemplate will use them.

Comment: but in the department json there are also other single json values which should not be treated as array. So code provided by you will affect them  ? updated my jsonString

Comment: So won't adding objectMapper.enable(ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY); will impact on my getDepartment as Department should be single object.Will it treat single department object as array ?

Comment: "Will it treat single department object as array?"-> no, this option only helps when you your java class declares array and the incoming json's field is only an object

Comment: Ok got it. Let me try it.

Comment: still getting the same error. Update the post with the added Configuration.

Comment: are these bean registered ? are these beans in a class annotated with @Configuration? is you @Configratuion class really used by the application?  are you using spring boot ?

Comment: btw the restTemplate has a setMessageConverters method, you can also set the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter object directly with it

Comment: I am using Spring 4 so class will be MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

Comment: Yes I am using Spring Boot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174935/discussion-between-manish-and-csenga).

Comment: Thanks, It worked. We have to manually set the converter in the RestTemplate.

Answer (score -3):

JSON is a javascript object notation. JSON is the same syntax as the javascript. In JSON, array values must be of type string, array, number, object boolean or null.